Safari Web Extension messaging not working as expected
I'm trying to send a message from my popup.js to my content.js script but the content.js script is not receiving it. content.js seems to not receive messages from popup or background scripts.
popup.js
window.onload = function() {
    browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { greeting: "hello from the popup" });
        browser.runtime.sendMessage({ tabId: tabs[0].id, greeting: "Going to background?"});
        debugger;
    });
}

content.js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Received request: ", request);
    return true;
});

background.js -- this one does receive the message
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Received request in the bg: ", request);

    browser.tabs.sendMessage(request.tabId, "Sent from bg");
});

manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,

    "name": "__MSG_extension_name__",
    "description": "__MSG_extension_description__",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
        "type": "module"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
    }],

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": "images/toolbar-icon.svg"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "nativeMessaging"
    ]
}


Just a guess, can you confirm that the content script is actually getting included? There is a bug in your json (comma at the end of "document_end"), and safari has the habit of then just ignoring the new extension (and run the old one)

I noticed that your manifest is using version 3 (MV3), but background scripts work differently in MV3 compared to Manifest Version 2 (MV2). In MV3, background scripts have been replaced by service workers, so your current approach may not work as expected.
You could try downgrading your manifest to MV2, where background scripts are still supported. This should help you determine if your content script is able to receive messages correctly.
However, if you prefer sticking with MV3, you'll need to adjust your code to use the new service worker approach. Make sure your service worker handles message passing correctly, as background scripts no longer run persistently in the same way they did in MV2.

According to mdn you can use a background page in v3, just not a persistent one. However since the background script seems to be working (and the content-script not) I don't think this is the solution.
